# How to know that year has been clicked in datepicker for year selection?

Tags: android, datepicker, material-design

I am using date picker layout in `cardview`. I want to perform some action on click of the year in `date picker` or after year selection I don't want to call `onDateChanged` method but when the date has been changed with the same year it should call `onDateChanged` method

Comment: Impement the onDateChanged method to first check if the year has indeed been changed?

Comment: @MehmetKologlu can't we just identify the year has been clicked for year selection

Comment: So you just want to select date from same year only?

Comment: @global_warming no, but i want to select date after year selection also but on dateChange method is being called before date selection as soon as i change the year

Comment: please share your code.